# Openxml - Embedded excel corrupts ppt

Tags: c#, asp.net, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

Powerpoint shows "Unable to read an object" after I embed the excel into powerpoint file via openxml. 
Am using a simple excel with a chart and a pptx created already.
This fails in both .NetCore and .NetFramework
Here is my code.

```
        string PPTFileName = @"c:\tmp\Example04.pptx";
        string spreadsheetFileName = @"c:\tmp\demoOut5.xlsx";
        using (PresentationDocument myPresDoc = PresentationDocument.Open(PPTFileName, true))
        {
            SlidePart slidePartBookMark = null;
            string chartPartIdBookMark = "";
            foreach (var slidePart in myPresDoc.PresentationPart.SlideParts)
            {
                if (slidePart.ChartParts.Any())
                {
                    slidePartBookMark = slidePart;

                    var chartPart = slidePart.ChartParts.First();
                    chartPartIdBookMark = slidePart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart);
                    slidePart.DeletePart(chartPart);
                    slidePart.Slide.Save();
                    break;
                }
            }
            var newChartPart = slidePartBookMark.AddNewPart<ChartPart>(chartPartIdBookMark);
            EmbeddedPackagePart embPackage = newChartPart
                    .AddNewPart<EmbeddedPackagePart>("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "rId1");
            embPackage.FeedData(new FileStream(@"c:\tmp\demoOut4.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.ExternalData ed = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.ExternalData();
            ed.Id = "rId1";

            slidePartBookMark.Slide.Save();
            myPresDoc.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
         }
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried opening a simple PPT presentation with the full chart in-place in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool and compared your code/XML with that of the "finished product" showed by the Tool?

Comment: I tried opening the generated powerpoint. Am getting the following error in openxml sdk - "ppt/slides/charts/chart3.xml:Root element is missing"

Comment: Not the one you generate - one you create in PowePoint, as a user, that works correctly. The error message is telling you that what you generated was done so incorrectly - it's missing a root element somewhere.